# Paymill NuGet package for MVVMCross: Exception while loading assemblies:

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, paymill

I faced a question with [PaymillWrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PaymillWrapper/) for `Xamarin.Android` with `MVVMCross`.

I installed the latest `version 3.3.0`.

And added it to my `App.cs`:

```
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Platform.IoC;
using PaymillWrapper;

namespace App.Core
{
    public class App : MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxApplication
    {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            CreatableTypes()
                .EndingWith("Service")
                .AsInterfaces()
                .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

            RegisterNavigationServiceAppStart<ViewModels.AppViewModel>();

            PaymillContext paymillContext = new PaymillContext("my-private-token");
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I try to call it from my `ViewModel`:

```
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using PaymillWrapper;
using PaymillWrapper.Models;
using PaymillWrapper.Service;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace App.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class AppViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
     ...

    PaymentService paymentService = paymillContext.PaymentService;

    public ICommand PayCommand => new MvxCommand(() => {

        Payment payment = paymentService.CreateWithTokenAsync("my-public-token").Result;
    });
```

But I can see the following error:
[image]

I tried to move initialization to `ViewModel`:

```
static PaymillContext paymillContext = new PaymillContext("my-private-token");

PaymentService paymentService = paymillContext.PaymentService;

public ICommand PayCommand => new MvxCommand(() => {

    Payment payment = paymentService.CreateWithTokenAsync("my-public-token").Result;
    });
```

In this case, I don't have underlines but the project doesn't build successfully:

```
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load assembly 'PaymillWrapper, Version=0.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. 
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'PaymillWrapper.dll'
   at 
Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at 
Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences
(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, 
AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at 
Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute
(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)    App.Droid
```

What am I missing here?

I tried this solution with different versions of `MVVMCross (5.2.1, 5.6.0, 5.7.0)`.

Comment: Clean the solution and delete bin and obj folder --> Delete all contents of the Packages folder (all the DLL's referenced through Nuget)
--> Restart the solution --> ReBuild (this will cause Nuget to get all DLL's again based on the packages.config)

Comment: @YorkShen, I tried but it didn't help me

Comment: Why do you think you can access `paymillContext` defined in `App.cs` in a totally different scope? Also `PaymillWrapper` NuGet package is .NET 4.5. Not compatible with Xamarin targets, you cannot load that.

Comment: @Cheesebaron, my colleagues successfully did it. So it's real.

Comment: It won't work at runtime. And the scoping thing I don't believe it. Unless it is a static field or property in the App class and you actually write `App.paymillContext`